# How to load multiple component which are at different places in the directory into the same view?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am a newbie here. I am stuck with a problem. I have **two** components which need to be loaded in the **app.component** based on clicks. So here is the scenario:
Two components:

**1. Hello component**

**2. Bye component**

Now in app.component.html I have a button **loadHelloComponent()** which loads the hello component  using dynamic component loading approach of angular. [Angular doc link for dynamic loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

In this hello component, I have a button which upon clicking runs function **loadByeComponent()** and
should load bye component

What should be the approach to implement this? I have to append both the templates in the app component but Bye component is dependent on Hello Component?

Here is the stackblitz link [Live editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loaded-c7ci3s?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Your help will teach me and save me a lot of time as I have already spent a day on it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is not a loadByeComponent function in your HelloComponent class so you cannot call it from it's template.

Is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loaded-n6non7?file=src/app/app.component.ts) what you are trying to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please check the link? It's not working

Comment: Weird, just checked here. It is working for me. I have attached a picture with the result

Comment: Yeah link is working now. No I don't want to  implement like this because this way if you check the  dev tool you will see  <app-hello><app-bye></app-bye></app-hello> .. bye component loads inside hello comp.  I want both of them to be separated  Do you have any idea how we can achieve this.?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue here is the [link](https://angular-dynamic-component-loaded-jjshli.stackblitz.io)

The thing is your were not following proper parent child relation.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. This i understand but the problem with this is bye loads inside hello comp. Its like <app-hello><app-bye></app-bye></app-hello> 
I want both of them to be separated

Comment: It is a separate component but if you do not want to dynamically load it then make some variable like isHidden and set that to false onClick and use ngIf to show and hide bye component